# Obfuscation+Reflection

Tags: c#

How can I get a PropertyInfo by name using GetType().GetProperty("MypropName") of a type which is obfuscated.

Comment: Surely you would need to know the obfuscated name?

Comment: Can you identify the property via it's type? That'd be more reliable than relying on the obfuscated name..

Comment: The type name might be obfuscated too, if it's a class in the same assembly

Comment: @harriyott, yeah, but you may be able to get the type without it's name (through a call to `GetType()` for instance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to know what the obfuscated name of the property ended up. That is very fragile as it may change from build to build. If you can tell which property is by other means (its type, custom attributes) it would be better.

The obfuscated name will mostly likely be a few non-printable characters or probably just `A`. Dotfuscator renames something like 80% of the code to `A`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to exclude the property from Obfuscation using the [ObfuscationAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.obfuscationattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the obfuscator, a mapping file might be generated. I've used this to lookup which properties have been mapped to which obfuscated ones. The problem is shipping the mapping file with the assembly kind of defeats the object of obfuscating.